# current library for iOS to consume RESTful web service

Tags: ios, web-services, rest

I have searched google for the different method and libraries used to consume a RESTful web service. But most of them are either outdated or failed to work when I tried the old libraries. This could be due to the fact that some of there were discontinued and not compatible with the new SDK.

I have tried SBJSON, ASIHTTP, stig's and jsonframework, but non of them seem to be working.

What are some of the current libraries that are being used in iOS to consume RESTful webservice? It will be helpful if anyone can give link to sample tutorial using the same libraries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try RestKit: http://restkit.org/

It is well known, popular, consumes XML as well as JSON and works with Core Data (response to NSManagedObjects mapping) which make great backend as a local cache.

Comment: Yep, i found a tutorial on that, gonna try it today.

Comment: do you have any good tutorial for it? I'm trying http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/restkit_ios-sdk/ and http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial but i seem to be getting error, and not able to compile it

Comment: I always find docs as the best tutorials. Besides, everything is explained and linked to on the github insallation guide: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

Comment: ok, I'll try to update my xcode before trying again. Using 4.3 for quite some time already, and it seem its for 4.4/4.5

Comment: Hi Lukasz, do you know of any good tutorial for testing out restkit? I have succesfully integrate the restkit project but am unable to find a tutorial to test it out.

Comment: From the restkit github info page: Visit your Xcode Preferences and view the Documentation tab. Click + and add the RestKit feed: feed://restkit.org/api/org.restkit.RestKit.atom

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you use iOS API classes like NSURLConnection? (iOS5 or above required I think)

You could invoke REST GET opperation for example like this:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[req setHTTPMethod:GET];
[NSURLRequest setAllowsAnyHTTPSCertificate:YES forHost:[url host]];//for https

connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
```

Where url should be an NSURL object pointing to your rest service operation url. And declare the corresponding delegate methods:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSHTTPURLResponse* httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse*)response;
    code = [httpResponse statusCode];

    NSLog(@"%@ %i",@"Response Status Code: ",code);

    [data setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)d {
    [self.data appendData:d];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                message:nil
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    self.connection = nil;
    self.data = nil;
}
```

connection, data and code could be local variables to your implementation class. In those variables you are going to store the connection made, the JSON data received (or whatever) and the response http code like 200, 404.

And finally if you are planning to invoke a secured REST service, dont forget to include the authenticationchallenge delegate.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {

            //set the user and password loged in
            NSString *username = @"username";
            NSString *password = @"password";                        

            NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:username
                                                                     password:password
                                                                      persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
            [[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

        }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, did not know that Apple has released their own class for consuming RESTful webservice. Couldn't find any information on google. Will try it out today :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in `NSURLSession` and `NSJSONSerialization` and then use Github's [Mantle](https://github.com/MantleFramework/Mantle) framework to map the JSON dictionary to your custom ObjC objects.